# How do I retrieve the protocols from the Rest Assured response and verify whether it is TLS 1.3?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

[image]

Please refer to the added picture. How can I get the TLS 1.3 protocol using Rest-Assured in automation scripts ?

Comment: youll only get a response if the TLS handshake has been successful...otherwise you wont have a response